# Windows api MessageBoxA can't run with a clean stack?

Tags: c++, windows, assembly, sdk, rootkit

i want to call a function with a clean stack which can cut off the call stack.

====================pseudocode begin=================================

stackBaseAddress = find stack base address by NtCurrentTeb

stackCurrentSize = stackBaseAddress - esp

backup stack

memset(esp, 0, stackCurrentSize)

MessageBoxA(0, "1", 0, 0)     <== here is problem, MessageBoxA fails, and GetLastError == 0

restore stack

=============================pseudocode end=====================================

if no memset(esp, 0, stackCurrentSize), everything goes well.

so i think there must be something in stack which cant erase, but what?

Comment: Messing with the stack is a recipe for disaster. And remember that there are often more things than just local variables and return addresses on the stack, like all the frame information . Clearing that away (with your `memset`) will really wreak havoc as the compiler expects certain data to be in certain places when it calls other functions.

Comment: What @JoachimPileborg says plus err... why?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg i know there is SEH in stack, but could you give me other thing in stack's information or some keywords to search

Comment: First of all, on Windows the frame and stack layout can actually differ from function to function, depending on if functions are declared "fastcall", "stdcall" etc. As for searching, the compiler name, version and "stack layout" might be a good start.

Comment: Can't reproduce, works fine for me (actually, I would be surprised if some fault would incur). Provide more info: what do you mean by "MessageBoxA fails"?

Comment: i don't know why u cant reproduce.Actually i erase all stack it must failed, or erase 0x100, everything goes well.